# Социальный плагин facebook сжатие js

Tags: javascript, facebook, плагин

Недавно заметил что при проверке сайта в PageSpeed Insights,[image: введите сюда описание изображения] рейтинг падает с 91 до 75 и появляется рекомендация включить сжатие для следующих ресурсов:

```
https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v2/yN/r/oZ8K6Rnrh4-.js
```

Который весит 217,5 КБ и подгружается через скрипт социального плагина facebook

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/ru_RU/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.4";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

На сервере, с которого идет загрузка скрипта сжатие для `js` не включено, это временно или у всех так стало? Кто знает, что делать? Удалить плагины, чтобы не терять в поисковых системах рейтинг?

Comment: Асинхронно не пробовали скрипты подключать?

Comment: Изменил код на асинхронную загрузку не помогло                          <div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '357910104309103',
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.4'
    });
  };

(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/ru_RU/sdk.js";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>